# Transfer file from local system to server using tunnelling

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I've some files in my local system generated every week, I want to move those file to my server "A".
Now the problem is server "A" is accessible from jump server using tunnelling.

To go to server A, I login to my jump server and from jump server i login to server A

I'm baffling around on how to achieve this in Python Script.

I've seen 
https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/
but I dont know how to put that in my case.

Comment: Do you have sshd on both the intermediate and the target server? Why do you need python? https://superuser.com/questions/276533/scp-files-via-intermediate-host

Comment: I'm planning to automate, transfer of file, so that I run a script and file moves.